# SE forbids the # sign in email addresses

Tags: bug, login, email

When I've tried to set up my account with a mail tag, it was rejected because the mail address weren't valid according to your verifier. My mail provider uses `#` as character for [address tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_tag_(Email)). When I've removed my address tag, I could sign up.

The `#` character is allowed in the local part of email addresses. Citing [RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696#section-3):

> Without quotes, local-parts may consist of any combination of
> alphabetic characters, digits, or any of the special characters ! # $
> % & ' * + - / = ?  ^ _ ` . { | } ~

There are lots of [best-practice](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Best_Practices#Email_validation) email validators on the web, and even on SE.

Comment: Wait, what? A _percent sign_ is allowed in e-mail addresses? What is the world coming to...